Temperature of a resting glass of water
It’s summer and summers have become more and more hot&humid lately. This got me curious about the dew point and then wet bulb temperatures, both for scientific and (maybe, someday in the future) survival reasons.
The following are clear to me, even from the names of the terms itself:

Dew point temperature is the temperature at which dew would start forming, if the ambient temperature could be dropped without changing the moisture content in the local atmosphere.
Wet bulb temperature is the temperature a wet surface is going towards as the water evaporates.
These two are almost always less than the ambient temperature.

I’m trying to relate these to the target temperature of my “dead body” (I don’t know what exactly this means, but it’s supposed to mean the state where all the chemical reactions, which produce heat, and all the r efforts to regulate its temperature are ceased) in a hot&humid summer at the time of dawn. To simplify things, I’ve landed upon this question:
The question: What is the temperature of a glass of water that has been long resting on a table, in a ventilated house with no air conditioning, and (if any important) in a hot&humid summer day/night? How is it related to wet/dry bulb and dew point temperatures?
